# Query produces data, but the export is blank

Tags: php, mysql, excel, mysqli, export

I was recently tasked to update some older sites from MySQL to MySQLi.

Though slow and steady, the update has been ok until I ran into an issue when exporting some data to an excel document.

This code was written by a previous developer.  There's a lot going on in the file, and I hope I'm grabbing the part that is supposed to be creating the excel document:

```
<?php
  $export = mysqli_query ( $session->connDB(),$sql ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysqli_error( ) );
  $fields = mysqli_num_fields ( $export );
  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows( $export );

  $pattern = '/[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9]\.[A-Z.]{2,6}/i'; //email
  $phonpat = '/(\(?([0-9]{3})+\)?[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{3})+[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{4})(( |-|\.)?[ext\.]+ ?\d+)|\(?([0-9]{3})+\)?[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{3})+[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{4}))/i'; //telephone
  $phPat = '/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/';
  $vippatt = '/VIP/i';

  for($f=0; $f<$fields; $f++){
    $header.='"'.mysqli_fetch_fields($export, $f).'"'."\t"; 
  }

  for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
    for($x=0; $x<$fields; $x++){
      $email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($export,$i,"EMAIL");
      $phone = mysqli_fetch_assoc($export,$i,"PHONE");
      $viprm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($export,$i,"VIP");

      preg_match ($pattern, $email, $matches);
      preg_match ($phonpat, $phone, $phoneno);
      preg_match ($vippatt, $viprm, $vpmatch);

      if(isset($matches[0])) {$emal=strtolower($matches[0]);} else {$emal="";}
      if(isset($vpmatch[0])) {$vips=strtoupper($vpmatch[0]);} else {$vips="";}
      if(isset($phoneno[0])) {$phne=preg_replace($phPat,'($1) $2-$3 ',formatPhone($phoneno[0],false,false));} else {$phne="";}
      
      if(mysqli_fetch_fields($export, $x)=='EMAIL'){
        $fld=$emal;
      } else {
        if(mysqli_fetch_fields($export, $x)=='PHONE'){
          $fld=$phne;
        } else {
          if(mysqli_fetch_fields($export, $x)=='VIP'){
            $fld=$vips;
          } else {
            if(mysqli_fetch_fields($export, $x)=='UNITS'){
              $fld=1;
            } else {
              $fld = mysqli_fetch_assoc($export,$i,mysqli_fetch_fields($export, $x));
            }
          }
        }
      }
      $data.= '"'.$fld.'"'."\t";
    }
    $data.="\n";
  }
?>
```

Here is where the code checks if the data is blank or not, and then exports the spreadsheet:

```
<?php
  if ($data == "") {
    $data = "\nNo records found for your search parameters.\n\n".$sql;
  } else {
    echo "should show data";
  }

  global $time;
  $time = time();
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CargoManagementCustomReport-$time.xls");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  print "$header\n$data";
?>
```

When the spreadsheet gets exported, I see "should show data".  This tells me the $data variable obviously has data.  It's just not getting into the spreadsheet.

If you'll notice in the above, I'm using mysqli_fetch_fields.  This was used to replace mysql_field_name (in my attempt to update to MySQLi).

I also tried mysqli_fetch_field, but got the same results.

I am getting no errors, but the spreadsheet is still blank.

I can echo $sql to get the query, and I can run the query in the database and it returns data.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you pick mysqli? Wouldn't it be simpler to upgrade straight to PDO?

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Insteaf of `mysqli_fetch_fields()` you are looking for `mysqli_fetch_field_direct()`

Comment: My team came to the conclusion that it would've been more difficult to upgrade to PDO.  What's done is done and we can't really go back at this point.  I added the argument to the error statement.  Still no results.

Comment: I will test mysqli_fetch_field_direct()....

Comment: No, please remove the whole `or die ( "Sql error : " . mysqli_error( ) )` and enable proper error reporting.

Comment: When using mysqli_fetch_field_direct(), I am getting the following error: "Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" which is pointing to the first for-loop:  $header.='"'.mysqli_fetch_field_direct($export, $f).'"'."\t";

Comment: Yeah, because it returns an object. If you don't know how to use a function you should read the documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php

Comment: I don't get it.  I went over the documentation and it seems that I am using the function correctly.

Comment: Also this doesn't produce a real Excel XLS file, it produces a tab delimited text file as far as I can see. Giving it an xls extension is a good way to confuse the receiving o/s. Excel might figure it out, and can certainly read tab-delimited files, but it's not the same as having all the features of the actual xls format, so it's a bad practise overall to give files a misleading extension.

Answer (score 2):

That whole code is gibberish, so I hope I understood what it is that it was meant to do.

Here are the main problems:

1. [`mysqli_fetch_fields()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) takes only 1 argument and returns an array of objects. You can't cast an array to a string. I assume you wanted to get the field name.
2. [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) takes only 1 argument and returns an array of data in an associative array as the name suggests. It also moves the internal pointer to the next row every time it is called. You are trying to use it as if it was `mysql_result()`.
3. Your nested loops are very messy. I replaced them with simple `foreach` loops and replaced the nested `if` statements with a `switch`. While I would normally stay away from such constructs, this is the easiest way to migrate this code.

After removing all the mysqli nonsense, the code is now readable. It iterates over every field of every row, applying some transformations to some fields and concatenating the result into a string.

Fixed code:

```
$conn = $session->connDB();
$export = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$pattern = '/[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9]\.[A-Z.]{2,6}/i'; //email
$phonpat = '/(\(?([0-9]{3})+\)?[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{3})+[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{4})(( |-|\.)?[ext\.]+ ?\d+)|\(?([0-9]{3})+\)?[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{3})+[\-\s\.]?([0-9]{4}))/i'; //telephone
$phPat = '/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/';
$vippatt = '/VIP/i';

foreach (mysqli_fetch_fields($result) as $field) {
    $header .= '"' . $field->name . '"' . "\t";
}

$data = '';
foreach ($export as $row) {
    foreach ($rows as $fieldName => $value) {
        switch ($fieldName) {
            case 'EMAIL':
                preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);
                $data .= '"' . (isset($matches[0]) ? strtolower($matches[0]) : '') . '"' . "\t";
                break;
            case 'PHONE':
                preg_match($phonpat, $value, $phoneno);
                $phne = "";
                if (isset($phoneno[0])) {
                    $phne = preg_replace($phPat, '($1) $2-$3 ', formatPhone($phoneno[0], false, false));
                }
                $data .= '"' . $phne . '"' . "\t";
                break;
            case 'VIP':
                preg_match($vippatt, $value, $vpmatch);
                $data .= '"' . (isset($vpmatch[0]) ? strtolower($vpmatch[0]) : '') . '"' . "\t";
                break;
            case 'UNITS':
                $data .= '"1"' . "\t";
                break;
            default:
                $data .= '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                break;
        }
    }

    $data .= "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm sure "gibberish" is the kindest word you could use to describe the code.  I've used worse words to describe it.  I didn't write it at all.  I've just been trying to update the MySQL functions.  I will test your suggestions and get back...

Comment: I updated the code per your suggestion, but unfortunately the document still comes out blank.

Comment: @JohnBeasley Then please update the question and show how you are calling this code and the contents of `$data`

Comment: I do appreciate your help.  A solution has been found that I will post here shortly.  I would post the rest of the code, but it was written by Azazel or some other demon.  I did upvote your answer though.